# Optimization my.cnf for 100+ wp databases and low RAM usage

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress, mariadb, lamp

I have VDS: 6 cores and 10GB RAM with 150+ WordPress sites.
All this things based on CentOS 7, ISPManager Web Panel with MariaDB 10.3 in Docker container.
Sites are not highload, but 3 times per week container shutting down becose RAM is low. (OOM  Killer killing it)
What .my.cnf parametrs can you reccomend for optimal and low RAM usage?
How i can stop this periodical container deaths that OOM Killer makes?
Maybe some system tweaks of CentOS7?
Tnx, sorry for mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many settings that can be decreased to help.  `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is *usually* the biggest, hence the first one to tweak.

10GB of RAM -- What is in that?  One MariaDB instance (with 150+ databases)?  Plus WP app code?

Lower `table_open_cache` a little.

Please provide the `GLOBAL STATUS` and `VARIABLEs` as discussed here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

`swappiness = 1` may help.

(from Comments)

MySQL/MariaDB would probably never need 100 cores; 3 cores is probably fine.

100 connections would probably never be *active* at the same time; `max_connections` is the configurable limit, 151 is the default (in some versions).

WordPress has some inefficient indexes on its tables; this extra CPU and/or I/O time spent.  That can be improved upon with this plugin:  [*WP Index Improvements*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

I think you have found the only tunable (`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`) that provides a tradeoff between speed and data loss.  Even there, the potential for loss is only during a crash.

What was your setting for `swappiness`?  If it was "0", or if there is no swap space allocated, then the system is configured to kill a process rather than crash whenever RAM is being over-committed.  A value of "1" says to delay swapping until you really have to.  I think "1" is optimal when a database is one of the main processes on the system.

Allocate some swap space if there is none now.  Use `top` or `htop` to monitor RAM, CPU, I/O, and swap usage.  I find that "normally" there is more RAM and swap being used than I can explain.

If CPU usage (or the "Load Average") is high, I suggest capturing the [*SlowLog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) .  Let's look at that to see which queries are consuming the most elapsed time.

A common CPU-waster (and/or I/O-waster) is the gratuitous calculation of "total number of rows" that a query would return.  The slowlog would point out which tables are big and wasting time on such calculations.  Then consider whether you can live without the value.  (Notice that search engines don't say "... out of [exactly] 987,654,321 matches".  There's a performance reason for that!)

Comment: Tnx, ill try it. Yes, one mariadb in with 150 wp sites with its own databases. WP app code? What is that? innodb_buffer_pool_size what size need to be? Mysql tuner says that 400mb needed, but in manuals usually says that need to be 80% of all RAM of server.

Comment: Are a web browser and php on the same server?

Comment: @AlexMacedonsky - How much data does MySQLTuner say you have?  There is no need to have the buffer_pool much bigger than that.  On the other side, for 10GB of RAM, I would not  go bigger than 7G.

Comment: now i see that RAM eating by php process...trying to find why.Big tnx for your help! Yes, php and web server on one server with db.

Comment: Don't let it swap.  Crank down the buffer_pool to avoid that.

Comment: tnx, mysqltuner reccomend 400mb for buffer pool, its ok or mysqltuner is crazy and 4gb at least needed?

Comment: @AlexMacedonsky - The buffer_pool is a "cache", so a larger value will _usually_ be better for performance than a smaller value.  However, there are extremes that need to be avoided.  Too _small_ --> severe sluggishness or even crashing.  To _large_ --> swapping, which is terrible for performance.  Neither MysqlTuner or I can predict what the "optimal" value is for your server, especially since neither of us knows how much of RAM is used by WP and its non-db components.

Comment: if i clearly understand,in modern world we need 100 cores on 100 
simultaneous connections,but if projects are not need to be very holistic and we have 3 cores with 6gb ram,we can't use big innodb_buffer_pool,but we can disable query_cache and make innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0;because 1 second of data is not critical loss in my case. What you think about this way of optimizations?A lot of guides are more about how to make performance, but nothing about-what i can disable if data loss is not critical and i need just working big amount of sites without regular content updates.

Comment: @AlexMacedonsky - You packed a lot in that one Comment.  I added to my Answer to address most of it.

Comment: @AlexMacedonsky - More specifically:  "need 100 cores on 100 simultaneous connections" -- No.  Most connections will be waiting on I/O or access to something (cache, buffer_pool, etc) and not really using any cores.  Compare `Max_used_connections` and `Threads_running`.  Even on _very_ busy systems, the first might be over 100 while the second is less than 10.  (They are not directly comparable.  The former is a high water mark since startup; the latter is essentially number of cores in use at the current instant.)